# Assembly Language: JE/JNE as an if-else

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, dosbox

So I'm trying to use `JE`/`JNE` to do an if-else statement. The problem is, it does not jump to where I want it to go.

What I'm trying to do here is to multiply 2 user-input numbers by using the `ADD` instruction and only **compare** and **jump** commands.

I was thinking of doing an if-else style but I couldn't continue because it could not jump to other labels.

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    str1 db "Enter first number: ","$" 
    
    str2 db 13,10,"Enter second number: ","$"
    
    str3 db 13,10,"The product of "
    num1 db ?, " & "
    num2 db ?, " is "
    prod db ? ,"$" 
    
.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,9
    lea dx, str1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,1
    int 21h ; takes user input for num1
    mov num1,al ; stores user input to variable input

    mov ah,9
    lea dx, str2
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,1
    int 21h ; takes user input for num2
    mov num2,al ; stores user input to variable input
    
    cmp num1,1 ; compare num1 to 1
    jne equals2 ; jump to equals2 if num1 != 1, otherwise, it will just continue
        mov al, num2
        mov prod, al
        
        mov ah,9
        lea dx, str3
        int 21h
        jmp endCode

equals2:        
        mov al, num2
        ADD al, al
        mov prod, al
        sub prod, 49 ; convert hex to decimal
        
        mov ah,9
        lea dx, str3
        int 21h

endCode:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
END
```

So if *num1* == 1, it's fine.

But when *num1* == 2 or more, it does not jump to *equals2*, instead, it just continues.

Here is the sample output:

> ```
> Enter first number: 2
> Enter second number: 4
> The product of 2 & 4 is 4
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> Enter first number: 2
> Enter second number: 4
> The product of 2 & 4 is 8
> ```

BTW, the user-input must be from 1 to 9.

Comment: The system call you use returns a single ASCII character.  This character has the value 48 to 58 for digits '0' to '9'.  You need to convert it to a digit by subtracting 48 first.

Comment: I modified the problem, btw, does the ASCII character have something to do with jump command?

Comment: Of course.  Your comparison with 1 will never be true because if you input 1, the system call returns 49 (the ASCII code for '1').  You have to convert the character to a digit before you perform any comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

When pressing the keys <kbd>0</kbd> ... <kbd>9</kbd>, the DOS.GetCharacter function 01h will return values in the range 48 ... 57 (the ASCII).

Normally you would want to convert these ASCII codes into the intended value simply by subtracting 48. However this particular program can do without that step.
You can compare with the ASCII value directly. It's the quotes that will make all the difference!

```
    mov al, num2
    cmp num1, '1'   <<< See the quotes 
    je  printCode
    add al, al
    sub al, 48      <<< Removing the duplicated bias
printcode:
    mov prod, al
    lea dx, str3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
endCode:
```